# In what case you would use non-UTC timezone on a server?

Tags: timezone, utc

I'm curious what would be someone's reasoning behind using a non-`UTC` timezone (esp. the one with daylight savings). I've noticed Gmail's email headers showing `PDT` (`UTC-0700`) timezone (in `Received` header), so I'm assuming that it's their servers are running at `PDT`, and I might be wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User preference, I guess.

If you have equipment and administration staff spread throughout several timezones, it's typically easiest to stick with UTC. If that's not the case, though, sometimes it's just as easy to use whatever timezone you reside in.

Comment: Right, but this reasoning doesn't seem good enough for Google which AFAIK has infrastructure/sysadmin teams in multiple locations throughout the world, and on top of that PDT has daylight savings, which is discouraged, and from what I've known is one of the reasons why UTC is preferred.

Thanks

Comment: @abbe - well then it falls under user preference.